# Vue v-model not showing the right default values

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I have a reusable `TextField` component in my Vue application. I now want to have a form where I first fetch some user data and then display it in that form so the user can edit their data. Everything works fine except that it doesn't show the values in the `TextField`. When I click on the 'submit' button it does show me the right values in the alert. However, it doesn't show the values in the form input.

I guess it has something to do with the `v-model` only using the `localValue` in my TextField component:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="localValue"
    :rules="rules"
    :counter="counter"
    :label="label"
    :required="required"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :type="type"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TextField",
  props: {
    rules: Array,
    counter: Number,
    label: String,
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    placeholder: String,
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    localValue: ""
  }),
  created() {
    this.localValue = this.value;
    this.$watch("localValue", value => {
      this.$emit("input", value);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

I created a CodeSandBox to show you my code, maybe someone can explain to me why it didn't work like I expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-currying-yvbp3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just miss the last part to add `value` in props of TextField Component.

```
export default {
  name: "TextField",
  props: {
    rules: Array,
    counter: Number,
    label: String,
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    placeholder: String,
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    },
    value:String
  },
  data: () => ({
    localValue: ""
  }),
  created() {
    this.localValue = this.value;
    this.$watch("localValue", value => {
      this.$emit("input", value);
    });
  }
};
```

wokring codepen- https://codesandbox.io/s/great-waterfall-nbm4o